# What causes the output to be in incorrect order? Python

Tags: python, sorting, combinations, partition

My goal is to take a one-dimensional list l as an argument and return all its partitions as a list. The function returns a three-dimensional Python list, where the lists contained in the second-level lists contain a total of the same elements as the entered list l without repetitions, and separately they contain all combinations of combinations like this.

Where I go wrong seems to be in the part where I'm required to sort the partitions.

This is my code:

```py
from itertools import combinations

def makecomb(l):
    def partition(collection):
        if len(collection) == 1:
            yield [collection]
            return

        first = collection[0]
        for smaller in partition(collection[1:]):
            for n, subset in enumerate(smaller):
                yield smaller[:n] + [[first] + subset] + smaller[n + 1:]
            yield [[first]] + smaller

    result = list(partition(l))

    unique_result = [list(map(list, set(map(tuple, part)))) for part in result]

    def custom_sort(item):
        return (len(item), tuple(sorted(item[0], key=lambda x: l.index(x))))

    sorted_result = sorted(unique_result, key=custom_sort)

    return sorted_result
```

This is what is expected as an output when calling `makecomb([1,2,3])`:

`[[[1], [2], [3]], [[1], [2, 3]], [[2], [1, 3]], [[3], [1, 2]], [[1, 2, 3]]]`

Instead I get this:

`[[[1, 2, 3]], [[1, 2], [3]], [[2], [1, 3]], [[2, 3], [1]], [[1], [2], [3]]]`

I have now tried different approached, but nothing produces the correct output. At best I've managed to get:

`[[[1], [2], [3]], [[1, 2], [3]], [[2], [1, 3]], [[2, 3], [1]], [[1, 2, 3]]]`

Comment: So what is wrong with your actual output (second output shown)? It seems to contain all the same elements shown in your expected output.

Comment: @quamrana The problem is the sorting method. The expected output requires a certain order. It requires that it is sorted from most elements to least elements

Comment: How would you describe, in English, the expected order of the items?

Comment: I stand corrected; their output is wrong. for the 2-element arrays in the middle, the format should be [1], [2, 3], and you only swap the element in the first element. Their output doesn't return the same 2-element arrays. So this is more an algorithm error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can get what you want with a double sort.

```py
from itertools import combinations

def makecomb(l):
    def partition(collection):
        if len(collection) == 1:
            yield [collection]
            return

        first = collection[0]
        for smaller in partition(collection[1:]):
            for n, subset in enumerate(smaller):
                yield smaller[:n] + [[first] + subset] + smaller[n + 1:]
            yield [[first]] + smaller

    result = list(partition(l))
    unique_result = [list(map(list, set(map(tuple, part)))) for part in result]
    for x in unique_result:
        x.sort(key=lambda item: (len(item), item))
    unique_result.sort(key=lambda item: (-len(item), item))
    return unique_result

print(makecomb([1,2,3]))
```

That should give you:

```
[[[1], [2], [3]], [[1], [2, 3]], [[2], [1, 3]], [[3], [1, 2]], [[1, 2, 3]]]
```